# Average thousands of partially overlapping rasters with GDAL

Tags: python, raster, gdal, rasterio

I have thousands of partially overlapping rasters that are each about 6500 x 6500 px, with a 500 px overlap on each of the four edges.

I am trying to merge them into one geotiff and average the overlapping regions. I have followed the guidance in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324602/averaging-overlapping-rasters-with-gdal) question, which came to the following conclusions.

1. `gdal_merge` and `gdal_translate` `-r average` options do not actually average overlapping regions
2. Using a Pixel Function and GDALBuildVRT will work

Based upon this, I have set up the following code to create a VRT, add a pixel function, and create a single TIF

```
out_name = "output"
tifs = ['tif1.tif', .... 'tif1235.tif']

gdal.BuildVRT(f'{out_name}.vrt', tifs, options=gdal.BuildVRTOptions(srcNodata=255, VRTNodata=255))

add_pixel_fn(f'{out_name}.vrt')

ds = gdal.Open(f'{out_name}.vrt')
translateoptions = gdal.TranslateOptions(gdal.ParseCommandLine("-ot Byte -co COMPRESS=LZW -a_nodata 255"))
ds = gdal.Translate(f'{out_name}.tif', ds, options=translateoptions)
```

Where the pixel function is defined as

```
def add_pixel_fn(filename: str) -> None:
    """inserts pixel-function into vrt file named 'filename'
    Args:
        filename (:obj:`string`): name of file, into which the function will be inserted
        resample_name (:obj:`string`): name of resampling method
    """

    header = """  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="1" subClass="VRTDerivedRasterBand">"""
    contents = """
    <PixelFunctionType>average</PixelFunctionType>
    <PixelFunctionLanguage>Python</PixelFunctionLanguage>
    <PixelFunctionCode><![CDATA[
from numba import jit
import numpy as np
@jit(nogil=True)
def average_jit(in_ar, out_ar, xoff, yoff, xsize, ysize, raster_xsize, raster_ysize, buf_radius, gt):
    np.mean(in_ar, axis = 0,out = out_ar, dtype = 'uint8')

def average(in_ar, out_ar, xoff, yoff, xsize, ysize, raster_xsize,raster_ysize, buf_radius, gt):
    average_jit(in_ar, out_ar, xoff, yoff, xsize, ysize, raster_xsize,raster_ysize, buf_radius, gt)
]]>
    </PixelFunctionCode>"""

    lines = open(filename, 'r').readlines()
    lines[3] = header
    lines.insert(4, contents)
    open(filename, 'w').write("".join(lines))
```

This works, but it:

a) Loads all the TIFs into RAM -- this is about 30+ gb, which is rough
b) Takes days to run

Curious if anyone knows of any faster way to approach this problem!

Comment: I am surprised that it tries to load all the files in memory, try writing a tiled TIFF (`-co TILED=YES`)

Comment: Similar problem regarding memory. Did this ever get solved?

Comment: maybe you could save the merged raster each time, then read it in again, and merge the next raster in the list? Thus stacking all your rasters on one file on the disc instead of loading everything into memory at once.